# How to pass Table columns values to an Array or String

Tags: arrays, postgresql, delphi, vcl

I Have table1 with the columns: ID,Fname,Lname .
Using Sql query i select the shown values

[image]

what i wan't to do is to pass the column ID values to an Array like that:

> MyArray[1,2,5]

or as string but it shoul be like :

> 1,2,3

So i can use them in PosgtreSQL query like:

> SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE ID = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,5])

the length of the array or the string depends on the selected values in the first table

Comment: Iterate the DataSet and create the string from ID field. Or use SQL statement: `SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM table1 WHERE <condition>)` Or use a JOIN statement.

Comment: Thank you that is work using SQL statement and i figured out how to pass the values to a String, but is there a way to pass the valuers to an Array ?

Comment: I assume you want the array in Delphi so you can construct the SQL statement `...WHERE ID = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,5])` in Delphi. What are you going to do with that array? convert it to a delimited string? You say you already figured out how to pass the values to a string.

Comment: you may knew that the ARRAY word in this statement `...WHERE ID = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,5])` is part of the PostgreSQL SQL. so yeah i knew how to pass it to a String and then put it inside the `[ ]` .
So it's just for the curiosity how to pass the values to a Delphi Array.

Comment: Why do you need ARRAY in SQL? use the statement `...WHERE ID IN (1,2,5)`. If you want to know how to use **dynamic** arrays in Delphi you can google it. Your array length should be `YourDataSet.RecordCount`.

Comment: OK thank you i should learn more about dynamic arrays . Thank you for your help

Comment: You are welcome, and good luck.